# Using Javascript to update a <li></li> from some data send from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, tabs

I have some Jquery tabs with Names on them.
(Ie: |Apple|Orange|Pear| )

I would like to update these titles to say something like

|Apple(2)|Orange|Pear(4)|

or something else based on the data returned by a php page ( say, numbers.php )

So, 
Jquery requests numbers.php
numbers.php returns
Apple:2
Pear:4

How can I have JS, then use that data to dynamically update the Jquery tab "titles" with the data returned?

Then, if I re run the function, it would ask for numbers.php again and once again, update the tab titles based on what php returns?

Also, the names could change.. So next time it runs, Apples may not exist, but Pear  may read 5 ..
In this instance, apple should be renamed "Apple"

Any help would be most excellent.
( hope ive made this clear? )

[ UPDATE ]
I have tried the below answer, but no luck.

The LI appears like this in the console:

```
<li id="tab-tabtestuser" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="newtab-tabtestuser" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="true"><a href="#newtab-tabtestuser" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5">tabtestuser <span class="count"></span></a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: What you want to do is quite clear, but why you don't manage to do it is not.
Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Guys, Ive followed the below example. and it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: All working, Below answer is 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return the data from `numbers.php` in a meaningful format such as JSON, you can then process the data and update the tabs in Javascript much more easily. Here is a basic example of what you want to do, you will probably want to improve upon it.

### `numbers.php`

```
{
    apple: 5,
    orange: 3,
    pear: 2
}
```

### Javascript:

```
$.getJSON( "numbers.php", function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

        $('#tab-' + key).find('span.count').text(val);

        if (val == 0) {
            $('#tab-' + key).hide();
        };

    });

});
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab-apple"><a href="#tabs-apple">Apple <span class="count"></span></a></li>
        <li id="tab-orange"><a href="#tabs-orange">Orange <span class="count"></span></a></li>
        <li id="tab-pear"><a href="#tabs-pear">Pear <span class="count"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-apple"></div>
    <div id="tabs-orange"></div>
    <div id="tabs-pear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, Ill change numbers.php to use json and see if it works.

Comment: Doh, Doesnt seem to work, Please see my update above :(